# Ubuntu FTP Server - Hetzner

Tags: 12.04, backup, ftp, database

I have an FTP Backup Server in Hetzner with details

```
Backup Server: u*****.your-backup.de
```

I am trying to connect to it through my ubuntu server using command

```
$ ftp u*****.your-backup.de
```

and i see `ftp>` then trying to upload my `Postgresql Database backup` file using command

```
ftp> put /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/rajedb.backup 
local: /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/rajedb.backup remote: /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/rajedb.backup
200 EPRT command successful
550 /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/rajedb.backup: No such file or directory
ftp> put /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/
local: /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/ remote: /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/
/home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/: not a plain file.
ftp> put /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/rajedb
local: /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/rajedb remote: /home/saksham/Dropbox/backup/rajedb
local: /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/rajedb: No such file or directory
```

Now my question is: How do i take backup of my files in hetzner server? and how do i download them when ever required?. and I want to take backup of my files for every 30minutes or 1hour.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to define the remote Directory.
Your command tries to put the file on /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/ but this directory doesn't exist on the remote backup server.

Try:

```
put /home/*myhomedir*/Dropbox/backup/rajedb.backup /
```

(See the last trailing slash?). That should work.