# Ubuntu FTP script to take backup and upload in my FTP server

Tags: 12.04, server, scripts, backup, ftp

Hie all
I am trying to backup of my application directory, database backup and then sending it to my ftp server at hetzner by using the following script and i get few errors

my server details: ubuntu12-04 (in hetzner)
database: postgresql8.4
my ftp server: hetzner
Trying to take backup at ubuntu12.04 server and copying in ftp my server

bakupscript.sh

```
site=ftp://u***.your-backup.de
username=u***
passwd=*******************
backupdir=/opt/openbravo-erp
filenameob="openbravo-erp.tar.gz"

echo "Creating a ob backup file $filenameob of $backupdir."

# Make a tar gzipped backup file
tar -cvzf /home/hetznerftp/"$filenameob" "$backupdir"

echo "creating a db backup file $filenamedb of ob database."
export PGPASSWORD="*my db password*"
backup_dir="/home/manideep/hetzner/"
#String to append to the name of the backup files
pg_dump -h localhost -U tad openbravo -Fc $i > $backup_dir$i\rajedb.backup

#login into ftp server
ftp -in <<EOF
open $ftp_site
user $username $passwd
bin
put /home/manideep/hetzner$filenameob 
put /home/manideep/hetznerftp/pgdump.backup
close 
bye
```

When i try executing that script through command `./backupscript.sh`

i get following error

```
Creating a backup file openbravo-erp.tar.gz of /opt/openbravo-erp.
creating a db backup file  of ob database.
./hetznerbkup.sh: line 28: warning: here-document at line 21 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
(to) usage: open host-name [port]
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
```

How do i send those files through script?

and Will this replace the existing files while i use command `put` in `ftp` in `ftp server`
if not how do i do it? thankyou

Answer (score 3):

Please avoid storing and transmitting credentials/passwords in plain text.

Instead setup SSH with public key only authorization and use scp or rsync for file transfer. Also let the `postgres` user himself do the backup via a cronjob (which is the answer to your [last question from there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381452/ubuntu-ftp-server-hetzner)), see [Ubuntuusers.de Wiki on cron](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron#Eine-Crontab-fuer-einen-Benutzer-einrichten).

Example for a postgres crontab:

```
# Shell variable for cron
SHELL=/bin/bash

# PATH variable for cron
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Backup some database from sunday to friday, compress with xz, hash with md5, delete obsolete backups after 40 days
0 3 * * SUN-FRI dump="some-database-$(date +\%Y\%m\%d-\%H\%M)-daily.sql"; cd /var/backups/postgres; pg_dump -Fc -Z0 some-database | xz -6 > ${dump}.xz; md5deep -kl ${dump}.xz > ${dump}.xz.md5; find -name "some-database*daily.sql.xz*" -mtime +40 -delete
```

Backing up files with tar as your Openbravo ERP or `www-data` user should be as easy as the above.

Edit: I recommend trying zstd instead of xz as a compressor, it has about 20 levels and is almost as good as the highest xz level on its highest level and still significantly faster.

Comment: `0 3 * * SUN-FRI dump="some-database-$(date +\%Y\%m\%d-\%H\%M)-daily.sql"; cd /var/backups/postgres; pg_dump -Fc -Z0 some-database | xz -6 > ${dump}.xz; md5deep -kl ${dump}.xz > ${dump}.xz.md5; find -name "some-database*daily.sql.xz*" -mtime +40 -delete` can u brief me a little on this command plz.. im confused with that

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xz.1.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put an EOF at the end of your script.

```
ftp -in <<EOF
open $ftp_site
user $username $passwd
bin
put /home/manideep/hetzner$filenameob 
put /home/manideep/hetznerftp/pgdump.backup
close 
bye
EOF
```